# Want to hide navbar on student page

Tags: reactjs

```js
//Header.js file
import React from 'react'
//import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Navbar} from "react-bootstrap";


const Header = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style={{ background: "rgb(199,240,224)" }}>
                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <Link class="navbar-brand" to="#">LOGO</Link>
                     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    
                
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/Signup">Signup</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/Dashboard">Student</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/Editprofile">EditProfile</Link>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </Navbar>
        </>
  );
}


export default Header
```

I want to hide navbar from Student page.
React version - 18.1.0
React router dom-6.0.2

Navbar file is saved as Header.js

Here is the App.js code

```
<Header />
<Routes>

  <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route path='/dashboard' element={
  <PrivateRoute>
    <Dashboard />
    </PrivateRoute>
  }
   />
  <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
  <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup />} />
  <Route path='/Student' element={<Student />} />
  <Route path='*' element={<Errror />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown called "switch".  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What is the react version you are using?

Comment: I am using react 18 version, I just want to hide navbar from student page ignore the switch statement, I tried but didn't get the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useLocation` inside your `Header` component in order to find the current path and hide the `Header` accordingly

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and then

```
const location = useLocation();
location.pathname.includes('Student') ? HIDE_COMPONENT : SHOW_COMPONENT
```

based on your code snippet, it would be sth like this

```
//Header.js file
import React from 'react'
//import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Navbar} from "react-bootstrap";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Header = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <> { !location.pathname.includes('Student')  ? (
            <Navbar class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style={{ background: "rgb(199,240,224)" }}>
                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <Link class="navbar-brand" to="#">LOGO</Link>
                     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    
                
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/Signup">Signup</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/Dashboard">Student</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/Editprofile">EditProfile</Link>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </Navbar>
                ) : null }
        </>
  );
}


export default Header
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more like where to exactly place these two lines and what in show and hide component?

Comment: Please share your header component too and I ll update my answer

Comment: Hi I have added the header in question. Please Have a look on that. Basically I want to do Login by Student and when Student will successfully logged into its dashboard there will be a new navbar (or the same navbar with students profile option or logout function).

Comment: Hey Now navbar is not at all visible on any page, can you please figure it out, but I really appreciate your efforts for trying to help me out. Waiting to hear from you back

Comment: sorry my mistake. it should be `!location.pathname.includes('Student')`

Comment: please dont forget to accept my answer too! the green tick!

Comment: done already..........Can you help me in implementing this from scratch 
( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74179553/dynamic-dropdown-with-fetching-api-in-react-and-springboot?noredirect=1#comment130969033_74179553 )

Comment: you need to add some code and show what you have done in order to help you :)

Comment: hi @Apostolos can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237631/data-fetch-using-api-reactjs